# Angular + Node.js + socket.io Locally its working fine but after deployed on Live server its get ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: node.js, angular, socket.io, port

Angular + Node.js + socket.io Locally its working fine but after deployed on Live server its get  ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Angular Code

```
url = 'wss://api.my:8000';
    constructor() {
        this.socket = io(this.url);
    }
```

Node.js code

```
require("dotenv").config();
var dateFormat = require('dateformat');
var mysql = require("mysql");
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http, {
    cors: {
        origin: "*"
    }
});

http.listen(8000, function () {
    console.log('Listening to port 8000');
});
```

Comment: You should probably check if the port 8000 is opened on the server. 
```telnet xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 8000```
where xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is replaced by public IP address of the server.

Comment: i'm using plesk server so how i can check available port on server

Comment: The above command is to be run from your local PC which will establish if the port 8000 is opened to outside world or not.
To be able to check if the node.js server is running on port 8000 in your server, you have to run this command in the terminal of your server once you login via ssh
`netstat -tulnp`